# Add a hardcoded string as the first row to the result of a SQL query

Tags: sql, hive

Is there a way to add a hardcoded string as the first row to the result of a SQL query?

For example, this query

```
select user_id
from users
limit 1
```

returns

```
123456789
```

But I'd like to add a string as the first row so the result of the query would be:

```
Hello, world!
123456789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`union`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). Have one query that returns a single row with "Hello, world!" and `union` that with your real query.

```
select 'Hello, world!'
union
select user_id from users limit 1
```